# Another favicon not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, favicon

I've read through and tried all the favicon fixes already posted. Including:

1. Refreshing the cache
2. Using a different favicon that works on other websites
3. Using a favicon generating website
4. Using a Photoshop favicon plugin
5. Using an absolute path
6. Using a relative path

It works fine in all the other browsers. I'm using IE8 in Vista via Parallels on a Mac.

It's on a Moodle website and I have not altered the default Moodle code for the favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $CFG->themewww .'/'. current_theme() ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

The site is here: http://www.olvarwood.com.au/olvarwoodonline/

Favicon path is here: http://www.olvarwood.com.au/olvarwoodonline/theme/olvar-wood/favicon.ico

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

favicons are funny things. I believe they may be cached differently to normal web content.

This may be because browsers (as well as other things) often request `favicon.ico` for every site they go to.

I've had favicons not working, and then miraculously appear several hours later.

Sorry if this isn't much help, but try waiting it out :)

Answer (score 1):

It works on my IE7. So it must be specific to IE8. The only thing I could suggest testing is to add:

```
type="image/x-icon"
```

in your link favicon element.

Comment: thanks, I just gave it a go but unfortunately still no joy :(