# How to clear IE's favicon cache?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, favicon

i have a favorite icon defined for my web-site:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Any browser that has visted the site *after* i added the icon can display the favicon fine. But my own browser refuses to show the icon.

i've tried every variation of the link i can think of:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="renamed.ico">
```

It doesn't matter, Internet Explorer (9) refuses to even try to do a fetch from the server (monitoring from fiddler).

i've tried clearing my cache, many times:

```
(gear) -> Internet Options -> General -> Delete -> Temporary Internet Files
```

[Alex in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823702/another-favicon-not-working-in-ie/2520371#2520371) believes that favorite icons are cached differently than regular web-content, and don't don't follow regular clearing rules.

So the question becomes: How do i clear the Internet Explorer favorite icon cache?

### See also

- [MSDN: How to Add a Shortcut Icon to a Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656(VS.85).aspx)
- [Why isn't my favicon appearing in IE7/8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931533/why-isnt-my-favicon-appearing-in-ie7-8)
- [favicon not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie)
- [How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)
- [Cannot get Favicon.ico to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201406/cannot-get-favicon-ico-to-display)
- [Another favicon not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823702/another-favicon-not-working-in-ie/2520371#2520371)
- [Favicon not showing, my icon is no good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912708/favicon-not-showing-my-icon-is-no-good)
- [favicon.ico cannot show on Internet explorer 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048354/favicon-ico-cannot-show-on-internet-explorer-7)
- [Why doesn't my favicon display for my web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732/why-no-favicon-for-my-web-site)
- [Favicon not showing, my icon is no good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912708/favicon-not-showing-my-icon-is-no-good)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling IE9? ;)

Comment: Have you tried `favicon.ico?xyz=123456` ?  Edit: Oh, you have renamed the icon. Never mind then

Comment: Can you show a live URL? Does IE9 even use Favicons any more? (Chrome for example doesn't)

Comment: i browse the same page from a different IE9 and it appears; as it does in Firefox and Chrome. It's something specific to this browser on this computer (i.e. cache)

Comment: @Pekka Actually, you win. Adding `favicon.ico?adsfadf` make IE perform a hit (which of course was 404). But then when i put it back to simply `favicon.ico` the icon shows up!  +1.  Now paste that in an answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It stores the presence or absence of a favicon in History.  If you want to reset it, clear your History.  [Here is a comprehensive FAQ](http://jeffcode.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-doesnt-favicon-for-my-site-appear.html).

---

**Edit:** Quoting the blog, calling it an extensive answer:

> why doesn't the favicon for my site
>   appear in IE7?
>
> *This is a re-posting of
>   a post originally published on
>   2007-03-01. The original can be found
>   [here](http://securitygarden.blogspot.com/2007/10/missing-favicon-in-ie7.html). This version has been updated to
>   match what is currently reality.*
>
> When I was at Microsoft, I was the
>   developer tasked with fixing the
>   Favicon story for IE7. The original
>   IE6 behavior was to download the
>   favicon once--when a user made a site
>   a Favorite. I do not want to go too
>   deep into the details of how this
>   craziness works, but the key piece of
>   information to understanding why it
>   seemed so broken is this: a mapping
>   between the url of the site the url
>   for the site's Favicon would be stored
>   in IE's History database and the
>   actually bits of the icon would be
>   stored in the temporary Internet files
>   folder. Thus, if you cleared your
>   history or your cache, or the item
>   expired out of either one, the icon
>   would be gone forever.
>
> Fast-forward to IE7. It has been over
>   two (three?) years since IE6 shipped.
>   We want to implement tabbed browsing,
>   and we want the tabs to display the
>   correct Favicons. So I updated the
>   Favicon code to always download the
>   icon on a first visit. The code also
>   remembers if there is no Favicon (404)
>   or it was invalid in some way
>   (ExtractIcon() failed).
>
> Here is a Mini-Faq (with one bonus
>   question at the end) that I wrote
>   while I was at Microsoft:
>
> **Q:** How do I make a favicon appear for
>   my site in IE7?
>   **A:** There are two ways.
>   The first is to put a file in the root
>   of your domain called `favicon.ico`. The
>   second is to use a `<link>` tag with the
>   `rel="shortcut icon"` value and the href
>   value set to the URL for the Icon you
>   wish to display.
>
> **Q:** How often does IE download the
>   favicon?
>   **A:** IE will download the icon
>   when a user first visits the site. The
>   icon is stored in the Temporary
>   Internet Files folder on the client
>   machine. Additional metadata about the
>   favicon is stored in the user's Url
>   History database. If either store is
>   cleared, or items relating to the
>   favicon have naturally expired, then
>   the icon will be downloaded again on
>   the next visit. If more than one page
>   (or site) shares the same favicon, it
>   is only downloaded once. IE takes
>   great pains to download the icon as
>   few times as possible to reduce load
>   on the server.
>
> **Q:** I see the wrong favicon for some
>   sites I visit. How do I fix this?
>   **A:** If the history database has become
>   corrupted in some way, this can
>   happen. The simplest solution is just
>   to use Delete Browsing History (on the
>   Tools menu) to clear the cache and the
>   history store.
>
> **Q:** I put a favicon.ico on my site as
>   you described, but it still doesn't
>   appear.
>   **A:** It must actually be a .ico
>   (an Icon) file. Bitmaps, pngs, gifs,
>   etc, will not work. IE7 will download
>   your favicon to the Temporary Internet
>   Files folder and call [`ExtractIcon()`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648068.aspx) on
>   the file. If this fails, we will show
>   the default icon instead of your
>   favicon.
>
> **Q:** I verified that my favicon really
>   is an icon, but it still doesn't
>   appear.
>   **A:** Since IE loads your icon
>   out of the Temporary Internet Files
>   folder, it must be able to actually
>   store it there. If you are setting the
>   no-cache directive for the icon file,
>   then IE will not be able to display
>   your icon and will display the default
>   icon instead. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) to
>   verify.
>
> **Q:** How do I create a different favicon
>   for every page on my site?
>   **A:** Put a
>   different tag on each page, pointing
>   to a different icon.
>
> **Q:** I changed my site's favicon to a
>   different icon, but the old one still
>   shows in IE. How do I force IE to
>   update?
>   **A:** If you just put the
>   favicon.ico file in the root of your
>   domain, IE doesn't have any way of
>   knowing if it changed. To force an
>   update, you need to use a tag and
>   point to a different filename than you
>   previously used. The current filename
>   is compared against the known filename
>   stored in the Url History database.
>   When IE sees the filename has changed,
>   it will download your new icon.
>   Alternatively, you can ask your users
>   to clear their history and cache
>   (Tools->Internet Options->Delete
>   Browsing History), which will also
>   force IE to download the new file.
>
> **Q:** What is still broken?
>   **A:** Two
>   things:
>
> 1. If you specify an
>      alternate location via  tag, the
>      href member must be fully-qualified
>      and does not respect the  tag.
> 2. The  tag must have "shortcut
>      icon" as the rel value, but this is in
>      violation of the W3C spec that says
>      whitespace in the rel tag denotes a
>      list of values. IE treats "shortcut
>      icon" as a single value. Luckily this
>      still works for other browsers who see
>      "shortcut" and ignore it and only pay
>      attention to the "icon" string.
>
> That should cover most of the
>   questions I've received about favicons
>   in IE7. If you have more questions,
>   feel free to ask.

Comment: I should mention that this may have changed in IE9: I'm not sure.

Comment: I had an issue with getting an updated favicon to show in IE9. I had to clear "Temporary Internet files" and "History" under "Delete Browsing History" to see it.

Comment: These rules have almost certainly changed in the most recent versions of IE.  If there is more up to date information, please feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: I confirm that in IE10 clearing "Temporary Internet files" and "History" was enough to solve the problem (if not, clean those when IE is not opened in your website, then restart the browser, then reopen the page). BTW I don't know why "Network Monitoring Tool" of IE doesn't show the favicon loading request...

Answer (score 16):

You can try circumventing any caching strategies using the crowbar: adding a random GET parameter.

```
 favicon.ico?def=abcdefghijklmn
```

it's hacky, but it often works where proper caching headers etc. do not.

Comment: Oooo, it's really close as to which answer i should accept. This answer really simply and directly solves the issue. jeffamaphone's answer explains *why* it works, but has a less friendly answer (destroying my history). At the same time you need the rep less. Bah, i think the other answer should be listed as *the* answer. It will help people coming along after the most.

Comment: If anyone is interested in how to do this in PHP, here's what I use:
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?refresh=<?php echo md5(rand(1000,9000)); ?>" />

Answer (score 4):

In both IE8 and IE9 you have to use absolute paths for the href.  Relative paths don't work, no matter what link rel you use.  type= is also not necessary.

The following has worked the best for me in all browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera and Sea Monkey):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://domain.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you browse to the favicon file directly (e.g. http://www.mydomain.com/favicon.ico) and then click F5 (sometimes Ctrl+F5) the icon will be updated.

This works in IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("~/favicon.ico?xyz=10001")" type="image/x-icon" />
```

**This fixed my problem, even though its a hack.**

Answer (score -1):

You will need to convert the image to .ico format. Save it to PNG or JPEG and then use this tool http://www.favicon.cc/ to convert to .ico format. Is not enough just save the image with .ico extension, you have to convert.

Comment: Hey ShoxWeb.  I have removed your signature from your posts per [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).