# Microsoft Windows and IE not handling images (favicons too)

Tags: html, favicon

I've read the SO posts regarding this and can not find a solution.

I've tried changing the link in the HTML to another location.  I've tried clearing all the browser data.  But, it still pulls a previous *favicon.ico*.

Does anyone know where it is getting this old favicon.ico? I should be able to delete it manually at a minimum.

This site process does not work.

http://www.phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/force-favicon-refresh.php

Actually answer might be here:
[How to clear IE's favicon cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970936/how-to-clear-ies-favicon-cache)

This is wrong too...clearing the browsing history and cache..does nothing to the favicon.ico file

O.K...there was a check box you have to de-select to keep it from saving favorites...this was not intuitive b.c. you have to select all the rest.

From there I changed the file name and link to in the HTML.

Then I waited about a day

Then it changed....I.E has some sort of timer..can anyone quantify this delay for it to pick up changes?

I've recently noticed that Windows 7 does not update images, that is if I save and image over and exiting image...windows will still display the old image until I click on it.  Probably related in some way to Microsoft's philosophy on updating images

Comment: I've seen about 3 posts..with people guessing on how to do this....

Comment: Is the site in question in your favorites?

Comment: yes...is this relevant...I actually went in to the folder hierachy...and deleted it already..but I did not find this relevant

Comment: Try putting the url of the favicon (e.g. example.com/favicon.ico) into the address bar, and refresh the page F5 and ctrl+F5. If all else fails you could just rename it to something like favicon2.ico and include that in in your html using the link element.