# DNN favicon icon will not show up in IE and other browsers

Tags: dotnetnuke, favicon

Probably a basic question for any DNN master, at the ADMIN level, how would i get the favicon i created for my new site, to actually show up in IE? It still shows the DNN favicon in IE, all the other browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc) are working fine with the new favicon i created.

Thanks again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically delete the favicon.ico file from the root of the website as well, that will be the DNN one. If you only have a single website running out of your DNN install, put your Favicon.ico in the root, in addition to configuring the site settings.

It's kind of a pain, but I find that to be the best approach. You might also then clear your IE cache.

Comment: I only have an Admin account so the only place i can add it is in the root folder, I had cleared the cache about a thousand times and no luck, but after digging online i figured out that there is a few different ways to clear it all so i did all those steps and at least now it just shows the IE icon, that's better than the DNN icon.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers display your favicon while IE is still showing the old, default one. This is typically because IE caches the favicon it found first.

[Clearing IE cache is more complex at it sounds.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970936/how-to-clear-ies-favicon-cache) You may struggle with this procedure.

My advice:

- Find the HTML code that declares the favicon (something like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />`)
- Add a parameter after the URL, so IE thinks there is a brand new file. For example, change the previous declaration to `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?param=dummy" />`
- Refresh your IE. It should display your new favicon.
- Restore the original declaration (ie. remove the extra parameter).

At this point, if you refresh your IE another time, you might see the default favicon again. This is not a problem, you now know that your visitors, who never accessed your site yet, will load your new favicon, not the old one.

Comment: I only have an Admin account, i don't have Host or Superuser access to DNN, can you change this with an Admin or will i have to let the people know who are granted that access? Thanks again.

Comment: I know a few things about favicons, but nothing about DNN, sorry... If editing the HTML code is too difficult (need to grant access, wait for someone else, etc.), try to clear IE cache, as suggested above.

Comment: I am a novice web developer, but i am pretty versed in HTML5 and CSS3, I just cant get to that snippet of code, but I will get with the people who are Hosts and get it fixed, thanks.