# No Favicon in Internet Explorer with Glassfish

Tags: angularjs, glassfish

I have a problem with the favicon in Internet Explorer.

My app is a project in glassfish v4.0.1.

Here is my page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=0.25,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
    <base href="/lso/">

    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <link rel='stylesheet' href="css/style.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <script src="scripts/gen/scripts.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The favicon is shown correctly in Firefox and chrome. But in IE the default favicon is shown (internet explorer logo).

I don't see a entry "GET favicon.ico" for internet explorer in the access log of glassfish. For chrome there is this entry:

Here is a extract for the request of chrome:

```
"13/Apr/2015:15:33:49 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 178
"13/Apr/2015:15:33:49 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 187 
"13/Apr/2015:15:33:49 +0100" "GET /myproject/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 4830 
"13/Apr/2015:15:35:13 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 178 
"13/Apr/2015:15:35:13 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 231 
"13/Apr/2015:15:35:14 +0100" "GET /myproject/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 4830 
"13/Apr/2015:15:35:14 +0100" "GET /myproject/css/style.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 123557
"13/Apr/2015:15:35:14 +0100" "GET /myproject/scripts/gen/scripts.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 363186
"13/Apr/2015:15:35:14 +0100" "GET /myproject/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
```

And here for internet explorer (where favicon.ico doesn't exist)

```
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:45 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 178 
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:45 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 178 
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:45 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 231 
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:45 +0100" "GET /myproject/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 4832
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:47 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 178 
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:47 +0100" "GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1" 302 231 
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:47 +0100" "GET /myproject/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 4832 
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:47 +0100" "GET /myproject/css/style.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 123557
"13/Apr/2015:15:47:47 +0100" "GET /myproject/scripts/gen/scripts.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 363186
```

If I create a new project in my second webserver (apache) and copy only the index.html and the favicons into it, it works in internet explorer. So I think some configurations for glassfish are wrong. Can it be possible?

Maybe someone can help me.
Kind regards

Comment: Is it possible, that the favicon will not be displayed, if a certificats error exists? This is our development project, so we have no correct certificat for it.

Comment: Works for me with Glassfish 4 in IE 11. Which IE version are you using?

Comment: I'm using IE 10 and 11 (on two different workstations).

Comment: I probably think this problem is related with the certificat error on our project. I will check this.

Comment: Have you checked everything from the list here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970936/how-to-clear-ies-favicon-cache?

Comment: Yes the favicon is a .ico-file. The hint with the GET-Parameter doesn't work either.