# I'm Using favicon for my site. But it is not loading in IE

Tags: html, asp.net, favicon

This is my code.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
```

Default IE icon is loaded. Please help me on this.

Its working when i run it locally. But when i publish my site to Azure it is not loading :(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please  add a [mcve] detailing what you have tried so far, why it does not work for you and what you want it to do.

Comment: Maybe it's the cache. You should [check the answers on this Stack Overflow question.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970936/how-to-clear-ies-favicon-cache

Answer (score 2):

This `~/` is not translated, use full path or just

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Its working when i run it locally. But when i publish my site to Azure it is not loading :(

Comment: @KliferdClinton Try to place the full url with the site, eg `http://www.example.com/favicon.ico`