# How to display favicon on offline webpages

Tags: css, html, icons, favicon

I am programming a website and I want to include a favicon icon to display my website symbol in the browser tab. I try previous stack overflow solution for this but none of them work. My problem is different because it works for certain browsers but not Microsoft edge or internet explorer and deals with browser compatibility.
My header code is below:

```
<head>
<!-- title  -->
<title> Wish List </title>

<!-- for compatiblity -->
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- website icon -->
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

<!-- css files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/list.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/side.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/modal.css">
</head>
```

Comment: I just realize my favicon display in fire fox and chrome but not in my current browser Microsoft edge and it does not display in internet explorer. I would like to create a browser compatible website so, it will display in all browsers.

Comment: Are you sure ie and edge are not caching the page with a missing favicon?

Comment: I refresh and reload the browser multiple times. I do not think so.

Comment: Are you doing hard or soft refresh?  Also worth checking the internet options caching and force it to clear.  IE can be a pain with its caching, it's way too aggressive for development

Comment: How do I hard refresh?

Comment: Using Ctrl+F5, or open the dev tools (F12) and refresh from there.

Comment: Hard refresh did not work.

Comment: Did you try clearing the internet explorer cache manually?  It's in internet options.

Comment: Deleting cache did not work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear IE's favicon cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970936/how-to-clear-ies-favicon-cache)

Comment: It still does not work, I even tried the online stackoverflow favicon it only display on chrome and fire fox.

Comment: Last idea...follow this site and it will generate you a set of images and html for favicon on all browsers...https://realfavicongenerator.net

Comment: It does not work.