# Laravel 5.6 favicon not showing

Tags: php, html, laravel, favicon

My project this Laravel 5.6 Ecommerce. Favicon does not appear, but the file path is correct ..

**Frontend**:

```
<head>              
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.luckykidstasarim.com/img/favicon.ico">
</head>
```

**Backend**:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.ico') }}">
```

Comment: [Browser] clear cache

Comment: It's been two weeks. I'm looking from another browser again.

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3970936/6413377)

Comment: I can see your favicon.ico displayed on browser tab. what is not working for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.ico') }}"  type='image/x-icon'>
```